# Suddenly getting exception "Word has encountered a problem"

Tags: c#, ms-word

This code has worked for about a year. Now I'm suddenly getting the exception "Word has encountered a problem". I have verified I can manually open the Word file (fileName). When I inspect the Word Application object I see that the AnswerWizard property shows a COMException. The appropriate Word project reference seems to be fine.

````
var appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var doc = new Document();
doc = appWord.Documents.Add(Template: fileName);
```
````

AnswerWizard exception:

> =>'((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass)appWord).AnswerWizard' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

From the Event log, System:

> The server-side authentication level policy does not allow the user SERA\EPBASVR$ SID (S-1-5-21-3869734172-4259265755-3048270987-18749) from address 192.168.40.204 to activate DCOM server. Please raise the activation authentication level at least to RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY in client application

Update: I have no idea why but this started working fine again after about two weeks on it's own. Maybe a MS update to Word?

Comment: We need to see the full error message from the COMException. Your image does not display it, which is one of the very reasons that we ask that you [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Error messages and code are both text, and should be copied and pasted directly into your question as such. Please [edit] your question to remove the image and add the actual error message.

Comment: Is this on a windows machine? Is it machine related? Can you post the error as stored in the system Event Log - use the EventViewer to locate the error - check for Application and System

Comment: @ChrisBD: It has to be on a Windows system - it threw a COMException, and that's only possible on Windows. The relevant information is in the COMException error message, which the OP has not provided.

Comment: @KenWhite: I edited the question. Sorry, this is my first ever question and didn't realize the image would be an issue.

Comment: @ChrisBD: Windows 10. I'm not sure this is the related error as there are many others just like it. This is in the System section: The server-side authentication level policy does not allow the user SERA\EPBASVR$ SID (S-1-5-21-3869734172-4259265755-3048270987-18749) from address 192.168.40.204 to activate DCOM server. Please raise the activation authentication level at least to RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY in client application

Comment: Hoping this might help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/564347/server-2019-update-kb5005568-sept-2021-forcing-new.html